# MemberCounter outputs wrong numbers

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I‘m trying my first member counter bot on Discord. Somehow the numbers of the online, idle and dnd members aren‘t updating correct anymore. It seems that the bot is outputting old numbers.

My code:

```
module.exports = async (client) => {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('889774617349218304');
    const guildMembers = await guild.members.fetch({ withPresences: true });
    const onlineCount = await guildMembers.filter(member =>!member.user.bot && member.presence?.status === "online").size
    setInterval(() =>{
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get('906111710706954251');
        channel.setName(` ${onlineCount.toLocaleString()}`);
        console.log('Updating User-Online Count');

    }, 360000);
}
```

Comment: Does your bot have presence intent enabled in the developer portal and code?

Comment: Yep. Otherwise it wouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, you are repeating the process where it changes the channel name, but using the whole variable. You are not updating the guildmember variable, hence it's always the same.

You could either move everything into the `setInterval` function, or redefine it.

For example:

```js
module.exports = async (client) => {
    setInterval( async () =>{
        const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('889774617349218304');
        const guildMembers = await guild.members.fetch({ withPresences: true });
        const onlineCount = await guildMembers.filter(member =>!member.user.bot && member.presence?.status === "online").size
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get('906111710706954251');
        channel.setName(` ${onlineCount.toLocaleString()}`);
        console.log('Updating User-Online Count');

    }, 360000);
}
```

This way, every hour, the bot will fetch the members of the guilds again, making it accurate.

Comment: This doesn't work because:
    "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules"

Comment: The `setInterval` needs to be`setInterval(async () =>...`

Comment: @MrMythical That was the solution! Thank you very much!